# iPad Safari CSS/Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I have 2 questions;

1. For fixing iPad Safari issues, do we only need to update in the CSS...I mean can there be any kind of issue which might require a JS update as well to fix for iPad.
2. Also through JS, is user-agent check the only option OR is @media which is used in CSS can be used in JS as well, as an if..else condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Depends what you're trying to do, but Mobile Safari has a very good rendering engine I don't see where you would need to tweak CSS with JS to make it work.
2. Yes you can target just the iPad with the following syntax:

"

```
@media only screen and (device-width: 768px) {
  /* For general iPad layouts */
}
```

[**More here**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/ipad-specific-css/)

Comment: Thanks..Actually I know how to detect from the CSS i.e. @media only screen ....
I wanted to know if the same is possible in JS...i.e. something like if (navigator.media.device-width is 768px)...hypothetically speaking..

Comment: Also will the iPad have a device-width of 768px always...I mean in both portrait/landscape orientations..

Comment: Is something like if (navigator.media.device-width is 768px) possible in Javascript ?